# ¿Como dar formato al Filtro Currency en Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

Estoy usando el filtro de currency en angular.js para la visualización del precio de un producto,el codigo y el resultado que me da es el siguiente:

```
{{ item.precio | currency  }}
```

resultado:

```
$15,000.00
```

¿Cómo puedo darle formato al filtro currency para eliminar los centavos?

Comment: con centavos dices la parte decimal ?

Comment: si me refiero a eliminar los decimales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta con poner :

```
 {{ item.precio | currency:undefined:0 }}
```

Si quieres 3 decimales, pones `3` , etc ...

---

Puedes cambiar `undefined` por la moneda que quieras (puede ir detrás) :
ej:

```
 {{ item.precio | currency: 0 : "€"}}
```

Comment: Mil Gracias eso era lo que necesitaba